# in given number x , can i check if x exist in the array with time complexity of log(n)+log(m)?

Tags: multidimensional-array, time-complexity, binary-search

Given a two-dimensional array sorted in size of NxM so that:
The rows are sorted from left to right - from large to small.
The cols are sorted from up to down - from large to small.

in given number `x` , can i check if `x` exist in the array with time complexity of

> log(n)+log(m)

?